# How to add white spaces in a field of Excel which is equal to length of a longer word

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a scenario where I want my Microsoft excel field to have the same length of the longest word in the column.
Basically lets say if I have:

```
ACBBASDBBADSAD
BADFDFDDF
```

So here I want to have the second word with less characters to have white spaces at its end to match the length of the first word.

`=&"    "` this definitely helps but I am unable to achieve the above scenario

Comment: better=&REPT(" ",len(longguy)-len(shortguy))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this screenshot:

[image]

In column B the length of each cell of column A is established with the formula `=len(A1)` copied down.

Cell D2 has the range name `MaximumLength` and the formula `=max(B:B)`.

With that in place, you can create the padded values with this formula in cell G1, copied down:

```
=A1&REPT("*",MaximumLength-LEN(A1))
```

If you don't want to use the helper column and helper cell, you can use this array formula instead:

```
=A2&REPT("*",MAX(LEN(A1:A15))-LEN(A2))
```

This formula must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter. It is advisable to use defined ranges, not whole columns in array formulas, hence the range in `LEN(A1:A15)`. Adjust as desired.

I've used the "*" character so it is visible. Replace it with a space " " in your scenario.

Comment: Also, @teylyn can this be done in a way to have a fixed width for each word so that they can align to the same width when copied and pasted in a notepad.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this formula to count maximum characters and use on some cell, because you will need to press a command for it to work, so every cell can't contain this formula, let's say it is on Z1:

```
=MAX(LEN($A:$A))
```

Certify to press `ctrl`+`shift`+`enter` on the formula

Then you use this formula on your cells:`=REPT(" ";Z1-LEN(A2))&A2`

Edit: Sorry, anwsered late, teylyn is more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Replace a token / separator and pad with spaces for example a part number and revision.

Global Shop example 17 char Pat number and revision starts at position 18.

=IF(ISERR(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"~"),1,2)), INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"~"),1,1),INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"~"),1,1)&REPT(" ",17-LEN(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"~"),1,1)))&INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"~"),1,2))